# Should I explicitly declare destructor as override in derived class?

Tags: c++11, overriding

Assume we have next code:

```
class ISampleInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~ISampleInterface() {} ;
    virtual void Method1() = 0;
    virtual void Method2() = 0;
};

class SampleClass : public ISampleInterface
{
public:
    SampleClass() { };
    ~SampleClass() override { };
    void Method1() { };
    void Method2() { };
};

int main()
{
    ISampleInterface *pObject = (ISampleInterface*)new SampleClass();
    delete pObject;
    return 0;
}
```

Is it better explicitly declare ~SampleClass() as **override** or don't care?

P.S. Please, focus on override and don't care the implementation of destructor itself. It could be defined, I just put example here in order to make my question clear.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do that. I also don't see any point in declaring explicitly a trivial destructor. Let the compiler do its job. You might need to introduce a `virtual` destructor into your class to (i) make the class polymorphic - although any function will do for that - and (ii) to assist in memory management, but that's not strictly relevant here.

Or, if you *must* do such a thing, consider using `= default` notation rather than supplying the empty body explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion but it is actually is not  the answer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO opinion any answer would be biased (i.e., opinion based). Generally, using the `override` specifier amongst many advantages has the advantage of eliminating:

- **inadvertent overriding** : Inadvertently override a virtual function by declaring a member function that accidentally has the same name and signature as a base class’s virtual member function.
- **signature mismatches**: Define a function in derived class that intended to override a virtual function in the base class but the two functions have different signatures.

[There are even people that back up the opinion that the use of `override` specifier should be mandatory in future version of C++.](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.de/2015/11/breaking-all-eggs-in-c.html)

Now, in the particular case of a destructor, attaching the `override` specifier seems to me a little verbose.

And I'll try to clear my stand. A destructor is a special member function. Considering a class hierarchy, a derived class's destructor overrides by default the destructor of the base class (that for the known reasons should be declared `virtual`). Furthermore, you don't have the advantages mentioned earlier (i.e., there can't be either inadvertent overriding nor signature mismatch in a case of a destructor).

Thus, I wouldn't specify a destructor `override`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found at least one reason why it is better to make destructor override.
`override` for destructors prevents to make mistake when destructor of interface base class is not declared as `virtual`.